# running hprof from sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, hprof

How do I run `hprof` from `sbt`?

Are there different options to profile the CPU vs. the heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't want to profile `sbt` itself so you'd have to use the `fork` mechanism and combine with the [hprof options](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html):

```
override def fork = forkRun("-agentlib:hprof=heap=sites" :: Nil)
```

or

```
override def fork = Some(new ForkScalaRun { 
  override def runJVMOptions = super.runJVMOptions ++
    Seq("-Xmx1999m", "-agentlib:hprof=heap=sites") 
  override def scalaJars = Seq(buildLibraryJar.asFile, buildCompilerJar.asFile)
})
```

Here are some sample options (use `-agentlib:hprof=help` for more help):

```
Option Name and Value  Description                    Default
---------------------  -----------                    -------
heap=dump|sites|all    heap profiling                 all
cpu=samples|times|old  CPU usage                      off
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for picking this up. This is what I currently have:     `override def fork = Some(new ForkScalaRun {
        override def runJVMOptions = super.runJVMOptions ++ Seq("-Xmx1999m")
        override def scalaJars = Seq(buildLibraryJar.asFile, buildCompilerJar.asFile)
    })` where would your code go?

Comment: @dsg - `-agentlib` is a JVM option and goes where the rest of the JVM options like `-Xmx` go.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness: If you are using a traditional `build.sbt`, you can also use

```
fork in run := true

javaOptions in run += "-agentlib:hprof=heap=sites"
```